# How to implement (or simulate) subtype polymorphism in PostgreSQL 9.2?

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, casting, enums, int

So guys, there's a big question I'm currently trying to answer: 'how to implement (or at least simulate) subtype polymorphism in PostgreSQL by myself', because I realized PostgreSQL's support to inheritance is somewhat undefined. So far, and put as much as simple and clear as I can, this is my approach:

```
CREATE TABLE TelephoneNumber (
   ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
   countryCode CountryCodes_e NOT NULL,
   operatorPrefix OperatorPrefixes_e,
   townPrefix TownPrefixes_e,
   coreNumber text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CellPhoneNumber (
   cellPhoneNumber_ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
   countryCode CountryCodes_e,
   operatorPrefix OperatorPrefixes_e,
   coreNumber text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE HomePhoneNumber (
   homePhoneNumber_ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
   countryCode CountryCodes_e,
   townPrefix TownPrefixes_e,
   coreNumber text NOT NULL
);

.
.
.

TABLE Operation (
   ...
   dateAndTime timestamp,
   receiverPhoneNumber int8 REFERENCES TelephoneNumber
   ...
);
```

Yeah, I know it may seem this solution sucks, since I'm copying same information into different tables, but that's the point: I'm implementing the consistency throughout the tables hierarchy simulating attribute's inheritance by child tables (since PostgreSQL won't let me reference the parent table *TelephoneNumber* into the foreign *Operation* table). What I want to do is inserting a row into the parent table, then propagating that row into the right *CellPhoneNumber* or *HomePhoneNumber* child table. (Please note that in my case child tables have less rows (1 each) than their parent).

Next, I wrote a trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertTelephoneNumberIntoProperTable_FNC() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF (NEW.operatorPrefix = 'N/A' AND NEW.townPrefix <> 'N/A') THEN
            EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO HomePhoneNumber VALUES(' || NEW.telephoneNumber_ID || ', ' || NEW.countryCode::CountryCodes_e || ', ' || NEW.townPrefix || ', ' || NEW.coreNumber|| ');' USING NEW;
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSE
            IF (NEW.operatorPrefix <> 'N/A' AND NEW.townPrefix = 'N/A') THEN
                EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO CellPhoneNumber VALUES(' || NEW.telephoneNumber_ID || ', ' || NEW.countryCode::CountryCodes_e || ', ' || NEW.operatorPrefix || ', ' || NEW.coreNumber|| ');' USING NEW;
                RETURN NEW;
            END IF;
        END IF;

        RAISE EXCEPTION 'ERROR: Row is not valid!';
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insertTelephoneNumberIntoProperTable_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT ON TelephoneNumber
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertTelephoneNumberIntoProperTable_FNC();
```

that will intercept INSERTs INTO *TelephoneNumber* table and determine which kind of phone number one is actually storing: if the **operatorPrefix** is equal to 'N/A' (which is a special value stored into the 'OperatorPrefixes_e' and 'TownPrefixes_e' enums) and **townPrefix** is not, then I'm sure it's a *HomePhoneNumber* instance. The same applies for *CellPhoneNumber* instances.

Problem is, when I `INSERT INTO TelephoneNumber VALUES(DEFAULT, '39', 'N/A', '010', '7708124');`, which we all know be a HomePhoneNumber instance, Postgres complains it cannot cast from int to enum, pointing the value '39' (the Italian international prefix, BTW). If I change the typer of the prefixes columns to, say, text Postgres will eventually not complain anymore, but values are correctly stored only into "parent" *TelephoneNumber* table as the effect of the trigger, but not in the "derived" *HomePhoneNumber* table, which suggests me the EXECUTE statements simply have no effect. So, my real questions are:

1. why cannot I convert those values into enum values in the EXECUTE statement? (I fear I'm doing it somehow wrong)
2. why, even changing the type of the prefix columns to text, the propagation to child tables has no effect?

The exact error I get when trying to cast int values to enum values is:

```
ERROR:  column "countrycode" is of type countrycodes_e but expression is of type integer
LINE 1: INSERT INTO HomePhoneNumber VALUES(1, 39, 010, 7708124);
                                              ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
QUERY:  INSERT INTO HomePhoneNumber VALUES(1, 39, 010, 7708124);
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inserttelephonenumberintopropertable_fnc() line 4 at EXECUTE statement
```

As you can see, I tried to cast the enum value in the EXECUTE statement, but had no luck. Hope you can help me, since it's 35 hrs. I'm awake fighting against pgAdmin III... D:

PS: I know I'll have to write more functions and triggers in order to guarantee the referential integrity throughout the hierarchy; the one above is just a sample in order to understand which route to take. Thanks everybody in advance!

Comment: I think you are missing the `inherits` clause in your sample `create table` statements. And I wouldn't store country prefixes as enums, those should get into a table of their own

Comment: As per the INHERITS clause, IMVHO it wouldn't help much in my case, isn't it? I mean, the only remarkable effect of doing that is having child rows stored into parent table, which is exactly the behavior I'm trying to emulate into the function. The reason I am using the function instead of the INHERITS clause is because this way I can build child tables by difference of attributes, which is an advantage in my case.

Comment: Regarding the enums, yeah, this might be a solution, but I still can't explain myself why storing the related attributes as simple text instead of enum values will prevent the propagation from working properly, as I asked in question 2. :/

Comment: With table inheritance you do put the differences into the child tables and the common attributes in the parent table. Although in your case the only common attribute would be the countryCode - probably not worth it then.

Comment: When I say 'difference' I do mean 'set subtraction'. :)

Answer (score 2):

> *why cannot I convert those values into enum values in the EXECUTE statement?*

Enum values are always character literals (which need to be enclosed in single quotes).

So you would need to do something like this:

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO HomePhoneNumber VALUES(' 
         || NEW.telephoneNumber_ID 
         || ', ''' || NEW.countryCode || ''', ' 
         || NEW.townPrefix || ', ' || NEW.coreNumber|| ');' USING NEW;
```

Note the added single quotes inside the expression to make the "country code" a character literal.

Comment: Great! This solved question #1, now TelephoneNumber table is populated, but HomePhoneNumber and CellPhoneNumber are not though, so question #2 remains open. I think it is because it's not possible to modify any table which is not the "referencing table" by the trigger: this is the reason I didn't write the INSERTs in the function merely as "INSERT INTO..", thinking that the EXECUTE would have act as a workaround, but I was wrong.